# Looking for short story about town heating up and 3 kids

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I thought it was a Ray Bradbury, but I can't seem to find it.

There's something going on where the world (or that town) is getting hotter and hotter, and there's three kids who have bikes. I think they go into this tunnel or something? And it gets hotter and hotter. I don't really remember, but I was hoping it might strike a chord in someone's memory.

I know it was a short story that was included in a collection of other short horror-ish sci-fi and fantasy stories. I think it had a red binding? I'm not 100% sure. This was something I read back in 8th grade a thousand years ago, so it might be a slightly hopeless endeavor. Somewhere back in 2003? I think.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to the site =) This is a good first post, but are there any other details you could add - possibly external details like when did you read it? Can you perhaps remember what was on the cover? Have a look at the list on [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and see if it jogs your memory

Comment: Hello, and thanks!  Annnd I didn't think of that, thank you for reminding me. I know it was a short story  that was included in a collection of other short... horror-ish sci-fi and fantasy stories. I think it had a red binding? I'm not 100% sure. This was something I read back in 8th grade a thousand years ago, so it might be a slightly hopeless endeavor. Somewhere back in 2003? I think.

Answer (score 2):

The story sounds vaguely like Dan Simmons' [*Summer of Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_of_Night) - though I haven't read the story in years.

[image]

An old school has been taken over by an evil entity and this entity creates a tunnel between the school and the bedroom of the main character and his younger brother.  The younger brother is sucked into the tunnel and the other kids have to go rescue him. 
It is summer.
The weather is getting hotter and hotter.
The kids do get around on bikes.
However, it is a novel, not a short story.

Goodluck  :-)